# While updating temporary object, main object also gets updated in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have two objects as mentioned below:

1. Main Object - Customers (having list of customer and each customer have basic customer details)
2. Temporary Object - Customer (having details of particular customer which User has selected on UI)

Now, if User is updating customer.name with XYZ from ABC, then Customers array object is also getting updated with that.

I am not able to understand why is it happening like this, I am not using ngModel or copying back from Customer to Customers.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using temporaryObj = originalObject

use
temporaryObj = angular.copy(originalObject)
or 
temporaryObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject))

hope it helps you

Comment: it worked, thanks for the quick and correct update. :)

Comment: you are welcome ng mark it as answer if working fine